# Suppose f is continuous in a region Ω. Prove that any two primitives of f (if they exist) differ by a constant

Tags: complex-analysis, complex-integration

Suppose $f$ is a complex-valued continuous function in a region $\Omega$. Prove that any two primitives of f (if
they exist) differ by a constant. The statement seems to be obvious but I am missing a rigorous concrete proof. Thanks in Advance.....

Comment: If $g,h$ are primitives, then $(g-h)' = g'-h' =f-f = 0$, so $g-h = c$

Comment: I suppose "region" implicitly includes "(path?) connected"?

Comment: @paulgarrett A region is a connected open set. Sometimes also stipulated to be non-empty, afaik.

Comment: @Vercassivelaunos, ah, thanks. But I do suspect that this convention is not universally respected/known. :)  When I teach complex analysis, I do not promote such conventions, but, rather, recommend to my students that they look at context and/or say what they mean, etc. In my experience, to behave otherwise is to invite wasted time over things with no serious mathematical substance. :)

Comment: @paulgarrett It might also possibly be a translation error. The usual object in the German literature is called "Gebiet", which literally translates to region. But it might actually be called domain in the English literature.

Answer (score 0):

You need the following thing:

> If $f: \Omega \to \mathbb C$ is holomorphic, where $\Omega$ is a domain, then: $f' = 0 \implies f$ is constant.

**Outline of proof:**

Write $f=u+iv$. That $f' = 0$ gives:

$$\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial u}{\partial y} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial x} = \frac{\partial v}{\partial y} = 0$$

Since $\Omega$ is open and connected, the region of $\mathbb R^2$ over which $u$ an $v$ are defined, which is identified with $\Omega$ through the identification of $\mathbb C$ and $\mathbb R^2$, is open connected. Connectedness implies "stairway-wise connectedness", i.e. that any two points in the set can be joined by a "stairway" (a union of arranged segments each parallel to either the $x$-axis or the $y$-axis). Now prove that $u$ and $v$ are constant on any such stairway, hence constant on the whole set. **Hint:** to do the latter thing, use, for a fixed $y$, the function $g(t) = u(t,y)$, and for a fixed $x$, the function $h(t) = u(x,t)$ (do the same for $v$).